# The problem of cyclic dependence in constructing the links between AuthService and FreshLink for OAuth2.0 authorization in GraphQL in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, oauth-2.0, graphql, refresh-token

In my project, I use the [fresh_graphql](https://pub.dev/packages/fresh_graphql) package to refresh tokens at the `GraphQLClient` link level. This package adds the access token to headers, manages token storage, and handles authorization errors, after which it refreshes the tokens.

I plan to create a similar link that will only add tokens to headers and handle authorization errors, so that token management can be done manually in the authorization service.

I have an `AuthService` that uses `AuthRepository` to make requests to the server. `AuthRepository` uses `GraphQLClient` to make requests to the server. `GraphQLClient` uses `FreshLink` to automatically refresh tokens. `FreshLink` uses `AuthService` to get the current tokens.

Listing `AuthService`:

```dart
class AuthService {
  final AuthRepository _authRepository;

  final _authenticationStatusController = StreamController<bool>.broadcast();

  const AuthService({
    required AuthRepository authRepository,
  }) : _authRepository = authRepository;

  bool get isAuthenticated => _authRepository.currentAuthTokens != null;

  Stream<bool> get authenticationStatus => _authenticationStatusController.stream;

  Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
    final authTokens = await _authRepository.login(email, password);
    
    _authenticationStatusController.add(true);

    await _authRepository.saveAuthTokens(authTokens);
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    await _authRepository.logout();
    await _authRepository.deleteAuthTokens();
    _authenticationStatusController.add(false);
  }

  Future<void> refreshTokens() async {
    final authTokens = await _authRepository.refreshTokens();

    await _authRepository.saveAuthTokens(authTokens);
  }

  Future<void> revokeTokens() async {
    await _authRepository.deleteAuthTokens();
    _authenticationStatusController.add(false);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _authenticationStatusController.close();
  }
}
```

Listing `AuthRepository`:

```dart
class AuthRepository {
  final GraphQLClient _graphQLClient;

  const AuthRepository({
    required GraphQLClient graphQLClient,
  }) : _graphQLClient = graphQLClient;

  Future<AuthTokens> login(String email, String password) async {
    const query = r'''
      mutation Login($email: String!, $password: String!) {
        login(email: $email, password: $password) { accessToken refreshToken } 
      }
      ''';

    final options = MutationOptions(
      document: gql(query),
      variables: {
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
      },
    );

    final result = await _graphQLClient.mutate(options);

    if (result.hasException) throw result.exception!;

    return AuthTokensGraphQL.fromJson(result.data!['login']);
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    // logout
  }

  AuthTokens? get currentAuthTokens {
    // fetch from local storage
  }

  Future<void> saveAuthTokens(AuthTokens authTokens) async {
    // save to local storage
  }

  Future<void> deleteAuthTokens() async {
    // delete from local storage
  }
}
```

Listing `FreshLink`:

```dart
class FreshLink extends Link {
  final AuthService _authService;

  FreshLink({
    required AuthService authService,
  }) : _authService = authService;

  @override
  Stream<Response> request(Request request, [NextLink? forward]) async* {
    // add access token to headers
    // do request
    // handle unauthorized error
  }
}
```

Listing `GraphQLClient`:

```dart
final freshLink = FreshLink(
  authService: authService,
);

final httpLink = HttpLink(
  'https://example.app/graphql',
);

final links = Link.from([freshLink, httpLink]);

final graphQLClient = GraphQLClient(
  cache: GraphQLCache(),
  link: links,
);
```

As you can see, `AuthService` uses `AuthRepository`, which uses `GraphQLClient`, which uses `FreshLink`, which uses `AuthService`.

How can I fix this problem?